# How to configure WordPress-like permalinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, url

I want to be able to have post permalinks appear in the root of the site. So, for example, a post with a permalink "hello-world" should appear as "mysite.com/hello-world", instead of "mysite.com/posts_controller/hello-world."

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you already have a "slug" field in your posts model. 
If your post controller has that into account, you just need to add the correct route for instance:

```
match '/:slug' => "Posts#show"
```

Otherwise, if don't have the slug in your model, you can use the [Stringex plugin](http://github.com/rsl/stringex). It's an easy way to automatic create slugs for your posts.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :title
end
```

It will create the slug from your title and save it to the slug column.

In the controller you can find the correct post like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
end
```

Comment: Can you chew this for me just a tad more? A request comes in as /post-title/, routes then sends it to the 'show' controller and then the controller should know what to do with it? Simply use params[:whatever] in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes:

```
match '/:slug' => "Posts#show"
```

Then in your controller you could do something like:

```
Post.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
```

Note: you will need to generate this slug value and store it in the `Post` model.

Also have a look at [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for a tried and tested way of doing this (if you need something more complex).